# Is there any relationship between the "theo" in "theoretical" and that in "theology"?

Tags: etymology, prefixes

The title is rather self-explanatory, but the notion that "theory" has some etymological connection, remote or intentional, to concepts of God i.e. "theology", is intriguing to me.

If they're entirely unrelated, ah well. But I would like to be informed.

Comment: There is a theological tradition going back to the sixth century which saw a link between vision (Greek theoria) and the business of theology.  And there was a philosophical/metaphysical/theological magazine published from 1966 to 1981 which explored that link called 'Theoria to theory; an international journal of science, philosophy, and contemplative religion.' http://catalog.hathitrust.org/Record/000639097

Comment: But that doesn't mean there is an etymological link, As all the answers show the root meanings are different and in the 6th Century too. (Zeus and Theos)/ (Theoria, horao)

Comment: @Hugh - see my update please .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the prefix theo- means "God" from which theology. Theory derived from "theoria" meaning "contemplation sight":

[Theo-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=theo-&allowed_in_frame=0)

> - **word-forming element meaning "god, gods, God,***" from comb. form of Greek theos "god," from PIE root *dhes-, root of words applied to various religious concepts, such as Latin feriae "holidays," festus "festive," fanum "te

[Theology](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=theology&allowed_in_frame=0)

> - mid-14c., "the science of religion, study of God and his relationship to humanity," from Old French theologie "philosophical study of Christian doctrine; Scripture" (14c.), from Latin theologia, from Greek theologia "an account of the gods," ***from theologos "one discoursing on the gods," from theos "god" (see theo-) + -logos "treating of" (see -logy)***. Meaning "a particular system of theology" is from 1660s.

[Theory](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=theory&allowed_in_frame=0)

> - 1590s, "conception, mental scheme," from Late Latin theoria (Jerome), ***from Greek theoria "contemplation, speculation; a looking at, viewing; a sight, show, spectacle, things looked at," from theorein "to consider,***  speculate, look at," from theoros "spectator," from thea "a view" (see theater) + horan "to see," possibly from PIE root *wer- (4) "to perceive" (see ward (n.)).

Etymonline

From [The Westminster PresbyterianA Ministry of the Presbytery of the United States](http://www.westminsterconfession.org/the-doctrines-of-grace/theory-and-theology.php):

> - ***An ancient, though erroneous, etymology of the word theoria viewed it as a derivative of theos. Although this etymology has been shown to be untenable, the word has both a background and a usage permeated with religious significance***.
> - A theoros was one who consulted an oracle or was present as a spectator at a religious feast. Theoria in the sense of philosophical contemplation or vision was cultivated by the Pythagoreans as a religious way of life. Plato uses the term to refer to metaphysical vision of the eternal forms in which mathematical order is fused with religious aspiration. Aristotle represents theoria both as the goal of human life and as that in which God's own blessedness consists.

Comment: Could you give your source for these quotes please?

Comment: @chaslyfromUK - etymonline, can you see the link?

Comment: @chaslyfromUK They're all from Etymonline.com (per the last line of the answer, or clicking through the links).

Comment: I wonder if the Greek theoria and the Greek Theos have any connection though? Or is the similarity solely coincidental?

Comment: @khaverim - theo- is from PIE "dhes" (term connected to religious concepts)   while theory is probably from PIE "wer" (perceive).

Comment: @Josh61 - You must have added it after I commented.

Comment: @khaverim isn't it comforting to know that Plato had the same thoughts?

Comment: To be clear, _theory/θεορία_ is not from PIE _*u̯er-_, only the last part of it, the verb ὁράω _horáō_ ‘see’, is. The first part, θέα _thea_ ‘view’ (Doric θάᾱ _thaā_, from earlier θάϝᾱ _thawā_) is related to θαῦμα _thauma_ ‘wonder, spectacle’, but I don’t think any further PIE etymology is known for that root.